# how can I make these diagrams with latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to prepare several diagrams with latex and the closest match to what I need to do are these two diagrams, can anyone provide hints how to do them? I'm familiar with TikZ but these diagrams look like advance level to me. Can anyone suggest a package/plugin etc to implement something like this?

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: If I had any idea where to start from to make something similar to that I would not be asking in the first place ... does it look like basic diagrams to you?

Comment: Use the TikZ package. Should not be too hard... two loops for the `G_{x,y}` entries, and afterwards some `\draw[->] node_a -- node_b;` for the arrows. The bottom diagrams should be even easier. Maybe you find some inspiration at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: That's the thing, for me TikZ is a matter of finding an example that +/- closely match what I need, and if can't find it then I can't figure it just like that. TikZ is very powerful but complex too, and not very intuitive.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's some code for the second part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\MyCross{\XSolid}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{scope}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-1mm] (mat1)
{
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \color{red}{\MyCross} & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
};
\draw[help lines] (mat1-4-2.north west) rectangle (mat1-5-7.south east);
\draw[-latex, shorten >=-3pt, shorten <=-3pt] (mat1-4-2) to[out=180,in=130] (mat1-5-2.160);
\node[anchor=south] at (mat1.north) {A};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.8cm]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-1mm] (mat2)
{
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  & \color{blue}{\MyCross} & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  &  &  & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & \MyCross \\
};
\draw[help lines] (mat2-4-4.north west) rectangle (mat2-5-7.south east);
\node[anchor=south] at (mat2.north) {B};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-1mm] (mat3)
{
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
};
\draw[help lines] (mat3-1-4.north west) rectangle (mat3-7-5.south east);
\node[anchor=south] at (mat3.north) {A};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=11.8cm]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-1mm] (mat4)
{
 \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  & \color{red}{\MyCross} & \MyCross & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  &  &  & \MyCross & \MyCross \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & \MyCross \\
};
\draw[help lines] (mat4-1-4.north west) rectangle (mat4-5-5.south east);
\draw[-latex, shorten >=-3pt, shorten <=-3pt] (mat4-5-5) to[out=270,in=-40] (mat4-5-4.-80);
\node[anchor=south] at (mat4.north) {B};
\end{scope}
\draw ( $ (mat2-1-7)!.5!(mat3-1-1) + (0,0.5) $ ) -- +(0,-4.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here'ssome code for the first part (building on **phimuemue**'s code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
  \node at (\x-.35,-0.6) {$v_{\x}$};
}
\clip (-0.3,-1.3) rectangle (8.3,4.3);
\foreach \x in {0,...,8} {
  \foreach \y in {0,...,4} {
    \node at  (\x cm,\y cm) (g-\x-\y) {$G_{\x,\y}$};
  }
}
\foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
  \foreach \x in {0,...,8} {
    \draw[->,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=7pt] (g-\x-\y) -- +(0,20pt);
  }
}
\foreach \y in {0,...,4} {
  \foreach \x in {0,...,7} {
    \draw[->,shorten >=2pt,shorten >=7pt] (g-\x-\y) -- +(20pt,0);
  }
}
\foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8} {
    \draw[->] (\x-.3,\y+.3) -- (\x - .6, \y+.6);  
  }
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,11} {
  \draw[dashed,thick] (\x-4.35,5) -- (\x + .65, 0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great nice! muchas gracias!

Comment: @GiovanniAzua ¡De nada! In some minutes I'll add some code for part one too ;-)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I've updated my answer.

Comment: Estas escapao! un millon de gracias!

Answer (score 5):

No complete working solution, but at least something to start with (for the first diagram, second ones should be simpler):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,8} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} {
      \node at  (\x cm,\y cm) {$G_{\x,\y}$};
      \draw[->] (\x-.3,\y+.3) -- (\x - .6, \y+.6);
      \draw[->] (\x-.2,\y+.3) -- (\x - .2, \y+.6);
      \draw[->] (\x+.3,\y) -- (\x + .6, \y);
    }
  }
  \foreach \x in {0,...,7} {
    \draw[dashed,thick] (\x-1.35,5) -- (\x + 3.65, 0);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```